# Download a full page with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to download the content a whole page using scrapy.

With selenium this is quite easy:

```
import os,sys
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
from selenium import webdriver


url = 'https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
content = driver.page_source
with open('source','w') as output:
    output.write(content)
```

But selenium is much slower than scrapy.

Is it an simple way to do in scrapy?

I want to save the code of each page in a different file text, not as a csv or json file.  Also, if posible without creating a project, which seems a bit of overkill for such a simple task.

Comment: Can you add some info why do you want use `scrapy`? Right now it seems that you need to download one page (without related scripts, images ...), and save it content (without any modification or grabbing data from it). Its easer to do with `requests` or even `urllib`.

Comment: @Arnial It's not one only page, there are several thousands, I use scrapy to extract the data one I have the source of the page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Code will download this page and save it in file `download-a-full-page-with-scrapy.html`

test_scr.py

```
import scrapy
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"

    start_urls = [
        "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233614/download-a-full-page-with-scrapy",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-1] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

run scrapy by this command

```
scrapy runspider test_scr.py
```

Comment: Can I set a user agent in that file?

Comment: In `test_scr.py` probably not (i don't know how), but you can set in in command line `scrapy runspider test_scr.py -s USER_AGENT="user agent name"`

Comment: You can most likely set an user agent using `spider.custom_settings`

     `custom_settings = {
        "USER_AGENT": "<user agent name>"
      }`

Comment: will this also download all the images and css files?