# Scrapy: Create Spider that Crawls Index Page and Saves Entire HTML Page of Each Corresponding Link

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy and am attempting to explore some of its capabilities.  I was hoping to succeed in creating a scraper that would crawl a set of links on a page --say an index page-- and save the full page as an HTML page for each corresponding link.  (The logic being that I could read the content offline at a later time, or create a scheduler once I graduate to using Scrapy's more advanced functions)

However, I seem to be stuck on this exercise.  I have a feeling that it is the erroneous way that I am looping --either the for loop, call back or return function.

My Spider.py code is as follows:

```
import urlparse
import scrapy

from scrapy.http import Request


class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "basic"
    allowed_domains = ["web"]

    start_urls = (
        'http://books.toscrape.com/',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
    # My Link Extractor
        next_selector = response.xpath(
            '//*[@class="nav nav-list"]/li/ul/li/a/@href'
            )
        for url in next_selector.extract():
            yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url),
                          callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
    # My Page Saver    
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-1] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
            return
```

I can get # My Link Extractor to work if I am pulling particular items following a desired XPath.  I suppose I could XPath the whole thing >>>response.xpath('html').extract()...but seems like there is a better way?

And I can get # My Page Saver to save a single link's page as HTML as adopted from [Download a full page with scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233614/download-a-full-page-with-scrapy).

However, I run into problems when I try to integrate the two. I have tried modifications to the for loop, callback and return command...but I am missing something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import urlparse
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

from scrapy.http import Request


class BooksSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "basic"
    allowed_domains = ["toscrape"]
    #                 ^ allowed domain should be name of domain that you wanna scrap
    start_urls = (
        'http://books.toscrape.com/',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
    # My Link Extractor
        next_page_urls = LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[@class="next"]').extract_links(response)
        # This is how we use LinkExtractor or you can create spider Rule for next page.
        # Read more about LinkExtractor form https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html
        for next_page in next_page_urls:
            yield Request(next_page.url,callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
    # My Page Saver    
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-1] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
            return
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Hmm...I expect that it works fine.  I am encountering the same problem as I experienced in this [experiment](https://pastebin.com/BANu2Nkz).  I am a total newb and I use flake 8 on atom to teach me format.  It flags lines that are longer than 79 charac.  I try to follow format (and flake accepts it) but i am wondering if it messes the code up? (keep in mind that I changed the allowed_domains as you instructed.

Comment: This [link](https://pastebin.com/4mG9wgnb) is the code I have lent from your above example.  Is my syntax from line 17-20 acceptable, or would this throw an error?

Comment: @dldatacowboy Ya I was more focusing on solution, therefore I didn't follow PEP8 guide line. But thanks for suggestion from next time I will keep that into consideration :) .

Comment: No...no...I wasn't criticizing.  I can't get the code to produce output.  All I get is this: [No Output](https://pastebin.com/rR0UWwSh) and I am wondering if it is becuase I use linter??  I am so confused.

Comment: @dldatacowboy you didn't get output because of wrong `allowed_domains`

Comment: @dldatacowboy if you accept my solution click on check-box on right to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Anurag!  I get output...but it seems limited to 1 HTML page.  Should I be amending `$scrapy crawl basic` in someway?  I want to have **every** link in the index produce an HTML page i.e.50 HTML pages: Travel - Crime.

Comment: @dldatacowboy modify you next page `xpath` to this `restrict_xpaths='//*[@class="next"]'`