# Scrapy save complete html file

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using `scrapy` for my crawler and it is working perfectly but i need to save the whole `html` file seperate from the `csv` file which i am writing. I don't know how to save the whole `html` file which I am parsing.

```
import scrapy
from myfirsttime.items import RItem
import csv

class RSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'Rspider'

    def start_requests(self):
        l = open('/home/ubuntu/Desktop/R.csv')
        data = csv.reader(l)
        for urls in data:
            yield scrapy.Request(urls[0])
```

Comment: here is the link for your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233614/download-a-full-page-with-scrapy

Answer (score 3):

You can do it inside the parse method of your spider

```
 def parse(self, response):
    with open('page.html', 'wb') as html_file:
        html_file.write(response.body)
```

This is the easiest way but you should read some documentation about middlewares in scrapy. Then you can create your own middleware which will save your html before parsing it. It can be a good option as you can activate/deactivate your middleware using the settings file. Have a look to the [Cache middleware](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?highlight=cache%20middleware#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache), it may help you to chose the right option.